# Problem with CakePHP model joins, missing fields from joined table.

Tags: cakephp, join, model

Im probably missing something painfully obvious here. Im trying to join multiple tables together in Cake, but Im only getting the fields from the first table. Consider the following code..

```
$joins = array();
$joins[] =  array(
            'table' => 'products', 
            'alias' => 'Product', 
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Device.id = Product.device_id'
            )
    );

$joins[] =  array(
            'table' => 'pricepoints', 
            'alias' => 'Pricepoints', 
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Pricepoints.product_id = Product.id'
            )
    ); 
$all_products = $this->Device->find('all', array("joins" => $joins);
```

And this returns the following SQL

```
SELECT `Device`.`id`, `Device`.`manufacturer_id`, `Device`.`name`, `Device`.`type_id`, `Manufacturer`.`id`, `Manufacturer`.`name` FROM `devices` AS `Device` LEFT JOIN products AS `Product` ON (`Device`.`id` = `Product`.`device_id`) LEFT JOIN pricepoints AS `Pricepoints` ON (`Pricepoints`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `manufacturers` AS `Manufacturer` ON (`Device`.`manufacturer_id` = `Manufacturer`.`id`)
```

ie. it only returns the fields from the parent Model ie. Device. How do I get  it to select ALL fields from the join? Im presuming its to do with the way I have my Model relationships set up, but I think I have these set up correctly.

Anyone any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can specify the fields in the find query:

```
$all_products = $this->Device->find('all', array("fields" => array('Device.*','Product.*','Pricepoints.*')
                                                 "joins" => $joins
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: as @pleasedontbelong said you need to specify the fields since you dont have it directly associated to your Device model. If you use associations as has many or belongsTo or HABTM you may use the recursive option to show the data related to the model that it fetched

Answer (score 1):

Do your join by calling bindModel() instead of manually specifying the join. See the cookbook for the details on [creating and destroying associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly-1045)